# How should SAML data be provided to the IDP?

Tags: node.js, express, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js to create an IdentityProvider and a ServiceProvider for a SP initiated single sign on.

I understand when the user goes to this login page, they will be redirected to the redirect URL with a query parameter 'SAMLRequest' that contains the request.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  sp.create_login_request_url(idp, {}, function(err, login_url, request_id) {
    if (err != null) return res.send(500)
    res.redirect(login_url)
  })
})
```

Then the redirect URL page should have a login form for the IDP which passes the login details and the SAMLRequest to the IDP? Is that correct? If so how is the SAMLRequest passed on to the IDP? is it just a form input? or should it be a header?

```
  app.post('/assert', function(req, res) {
    var options = {request_body: req.body}
    sp.post_assert(idp, options, function(error, saml_response) {
      if (error != null) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.sendStatus(500)
      }
      res.sendStatus(`Hello ${saml_response.user.name_id}!`)
   })
  })
```

Comment: An SAMLv2 compliant IdP is far more than just handling SAML protocol messages. I doubt it's a peace of cake to build SAML compliant IdP. Why do you need to implement one yourself instead of using an exiting one?

Comment: The redirect URL is hosted as part of the IdP. The idp receives a SAML request from a SP, presents login UI or equivalent to authenticate the user, then generates the SAMLResponse and posts it to the callback URL on the SP where it validates the response and presumably logs the identity in that was asserted by the IdP.

Comment: The assert endpoint you have is on the SP as well, it is called by the IdP after authentication is complete. Basically all the code you’ve shown is SP-side.  It’s not entirely clear what you are trying to do so not sure if I’ve answered anything